# Electron movement between compounds in reaction schemes

Tags: chemfig

I tried to draw some reaction schemes with some electron movements using the `chemfig` macros.

Problem is: I can draw every electron movement but in schemes only inside a certain compound of the reaction. If the nodes for the drawn arrow are in different compounds the arrow appears anywhere else but where I want it to. Same happens if the `\chemmove`-order is posted after a compound-differing arrow. Meaning it looks like the nodes get somehow "spoiled" once there is an arrow slicing compounds between the nodes and the `\chemmove` part.

Here are some examples.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\setchemrel{}{}{8em}
\chemfig{R-[:30](-[:-30,.25,,,draw=none]@{fp}\fplus)=^[:90]O}
\chemrel[\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=[@{b}])}][]{<>}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
\draw[->,red,shorten >=3pt, shorten <=3pt]
(b) .. controls +(-120:8mm) and +(-90:8mm) .. (fp) ;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{R-[:30](-[:-30,.25,,,draw=none]@{fp}\fplus)=^[:90]O}
\arrow{<=>[*{0}\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=[@{b}])}]}[,1.5]
\schemestop
\chemmove{
\draw[->,red,shorten >=3pt, shorten <=3pt]
(b) .. controls +(-120:8mm) and +(-90:8mm) .. (fp) ;
}
\end{document}
```

I tried to work around it by using `\chemrel` instead of `\arrow` but this makes alignments horrible.

Comment: Try placing `\chemmove` *after* `\schemestop`. `mychemistry` is rather unmaintained but if you notice something not working you could tell the author, anyway

Comment: Tried it, same results. Thx for the editing btw, I'm a newbie here.

Comment: In this case we're going to need a complete and compilable example (a MWE) with which we can reproduce the behaviour. In principle `\chemmove` and `\arrow` *can* be combined (see http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5734#5738 for an example...)

Comment: My header is rather big as I am writing my PhD with it but I do get similar results with the example you sent in the comment, so I will edit the question with a different (easier), complete and compilable example which should have the same problem. I am using TexNic Center 1.0 Stable Release Candidate 1 with a LaTex=>PS=>PDF Compilation

Comment: We don't need your complete header. `\usepackage{chemfig}` should suffice. What we need is to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem when compiling with latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf. When I compile with pdflatex the example works as it should

Comment: True story, Compilation with LaTex=>PDF does the job.... For me this means just to use `\usepackage{epstopdf}` for my pictures and the LaTex=>pdf compilation. I think we can see this problem then solved? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears when you use a compilation over PS to PDF. If you want to make reaction schemes using `\usepackage{chemfig}` you should compile with pdflatex (LaTex=>PDF).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (not very nice) would be to manually adjust all the offsets.
This should work also if compiled over PS to PDF:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{R-[:30](-[:-30,.25,,,draw=none]@{fp}\fplus)=^[:90]O}
\arrow(.340--){<=>[*{0}\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=[@{b}])}]}[,1.5]
\schemestop
\chemmove[->,red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=3pt]{
\draw([yshift=40pt,xshift=20pt]fp.190)..controls+(-95:8mm)and+(-90:8mm)..([yshift=-4pt,xshift=35pt]b);}

\end{document}
```